# How can I handle with DBI this command "set Pagesize 50"

Tags: perl, dbi

Hi I am trying to set Pagesize with DBI and script fails any recommendation how can I hndle this with DBI:

```
$dbh=DBI->connect( "dbi:Oracle:", "", "", { ora_session_mode =>
ORA_SYSDBA , RaiseError => 1, PrintError => 1 } );
$dbh->do(qq{ " SET PAGESIZE 50"   } );
```

There is error:

> DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (DBD
>   ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 1 in ' <*>" SET
>   PAGESIZE 50"   ') [for Statement " " SET PAGESIZE 50"   "] at run.pl
>   line 9. DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
>   (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 1 in ' <*>" SET
>   PAGESIZE 50"   ') [for Statement " " SET PAGESIZE 50"   "] at run.pl
>   line 9.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quoting things twice in that statement on accident.

So oracle is seeing this command get sent to it:`" SET PAGESIZE 50"`

`qq{}` is essentially an alternate way of doing double quotes in perl so that you don't have to escape double quotes inside. So just remove the double quotes from inside and it will be happy (or use double quotes instead of qq, but, since you sometimes want double quotes in SQL, using the brackets is safer)

```
$dbh->do( qq{SET PAGESIZE 50} );
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not an actual SQL command, it's a configuration command for Oracle's SQLPLUS client that isn't sent to the server. You aren't using SQLPLUS, and it doesn't make any sense to issue that command with DBI.